# get uid after imap_append

Tags: php, imap

How is it possible to get the uid from the new message appended to the IMAP server with `imap_append` ??

```
imap_append($this->stream, $this->folders['inbox'], $body, '\\Seen');
```

Comment: Try to use `imap_search()` with your message details as criteria.

Comment: alot messages have the same `subject` so that would be hard to distinguish the new message

Comment: But you can also try to add more criteria like date.

Comment: [Not PHP]  Assuming your server is not so sad that it doesn't support UIDPLUS, the IMAP OK response should include the UID of the new message.  I would hope the PHP library would expose this.